# High I/O wait after login

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've noticed that the ubuntuone-syncdaemon hogs up the hard disk every time I log in to Ubuntu (10.04). This takes up to two or three minutes, which makes Ubuntu insufferably slow. Opening Firefox is okay, but the browser is constantly greyed out and lags horribly.

Given that I often shut down my laptop when I don't use it (about 3 to 4 times a day), this makes Ubuntu lose much of its lustre because of its long boot time. Is this a normal behaviour of Ubuntu One? Is it intended?

Note that I've actually posted this in the forums [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1667581), but I received only few replies.

Comment: It is possible to limit the bandwidth for each computer you have attached to Ubuntu one.

If you open the Ubuntu One control panel and go to the devices tab you can set a specific maximum upload and download limits.

This is a suggested workaround to your problem and not a fix.

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not the uploading/downloading, but that, upon the starting of the sync daemon, it scans my hard disk for minutes, resulting in high I/O wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue in ubuntuone-syncdaemon versions prior to what's currently in Natty. We're working on getting backports of the fix to this (and many more) issues backported to 10.04; unfortunately we didn't make it in time for 10.04.2, but we'll try to get things into a PPA soon (within a month or so). I'll update this answer when we do that.

Comment: So does it mean that Natty will not suffer the same problem? What about Maverick? If so, I can't wait for April!

Comment: @Jackson It is already in Natty, yes. I doubt we'll backport the feature to Maverick (but if you're feeling adventurous you could try the nightlies ppa -- but I'm not going to link it from here).